# Ruby: interpolated string to variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Ruby, how can I interpolate a string to make a variable name?

I want to be able to set a variable like so:

```
"post_#{id}" = true
```

This returns a syntax error, funnily enough:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: Generally, the need to do this is a code smell, indicating bad choice of data structures. Instead of individual variables `post_1`, `post_2`, `post_N` it is better (in every imaginable way) to have, for example, a hash, `post = { 1 => true, 2 => true, ...}`.

Comment: @Jörg, the OP did not ask how one can create a local variable dynamically. He/she may only want to know how to get or set an existing local variable dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can do something like:

```
  send("post_#{id}=", true)
```

That would require, of course, that you have appropriate setter/getter. Which, since you're doing this dynamically, you probably don't.

So, perhaps you could do:

```
  instance_variable_set("@post_#{id}",true)
```

To retrieve the variable:

```
  instance_variable_get("@post_#{id}")
```

BTW, if you get tired of typing `instance_variable_set("@post_#{id}",true)`, just for fun you *could* do something like:

```
class Foo

  def dynamic_accessor(name) 
    class_eval do 
      define_method "#{name}" do
        instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
      end
      define_method "#{name}=" do |val|
        instance_variable_set("@#{name}",val)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

In which case you could:

```
2.3.1 :017 > id = 2
 => 2 
2.3.1 :018 > f = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x00000005436f20> 
2.3.1 :019 > f.dynamic_accessor("post_#{id}")
 => :post_2= 
2.3.1 :020 > f.send("post_#{id}=", true)
 => true 
2.3.1 :021 > f.send("post_#{id}")
 => true 
2.3.1 :022 > f.send("post_#{id}=", "bar")
 => "bar" 
2.3.1 :023 > f.send("post_#{id}")
 => "bar"
```

Comment: Yeah, `send` is out, `instance_variable_set` works nicely. It requires the `@` prefix though, but that's a pretty easy fix and totally makes sense given the name of the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This concerns the getting and setting of local variables. Suppose

```
id = 1
s = "post_#{id}"
  #=> "post_1"
```

Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically. Therefore, if a local variable `post_1` does not exist, the *only* way you can create it is by using an assignment statement:

```
post_1 = false
```

If the local variable `post_1` exists, you can retrieve its value dynamically with

```
b = binding
b.local_variable_get(s)
  #=> false
```

(or `b.local_variable_get(s.to_sym)`) and set its value dynamically with

```
b.local_variable_set(s, true)
  #=> true
post_1
  #=> true
```

(or `b.local_variable_set(s.to_sym, true)`).

See [Binding#local_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) and [Binding#local_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set).